# Smooth Gaussian Fit with small data

Tags: python, curve-fitting, gaussian, data-fitting

I want to apply a gaussian fit as shown in my code below. The problem is that i only got a small amount of data points to fit so the curve does not look like a proper gaussian curve.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import asarray as ar, exp, sqrt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit


x = [63.8, 69.9, 76, 82.1, 88.2, 94.3, 100.4]
y = [124, 349, 1793, 5143, 2782, 174, -9]

amp1 = 5150
sigma1 = 10
cen1 = 81

def gaus(x, amp1,cen1,sigma1):
    return amp1*(1/(sigma1*(np.sqrt(2*np.pi))))*(np.exp((-1.0/2.0)*(((x-cen1)/sigma1)**2)))

popt_gauss, pcov_gauss = curve_fit(gaus, x, y, p0=[amp1, cen1, sigma1])
perr_gauss = np.sqrt(np.diag(pcov_gauss))

plt.plot(x, y, color="red", linewidth=1, label="Gauß-Fitfunktion")
plt.scatter(x, y, color="black", marker=".", s=30)

plt.show()
```

Is there a way to fix this without adding more values?

Answer (score 0):

right now you are plotting the same values. The `curve_fit` returns the coefficients to fit the gauss function to your data in the variable `popt_gauss`.

You could use these coefficients to now build the fitting data:

```
x_fit = np.linspace(x[0], x[-1], 100)
y_fit = gauss(x_fit, popt_gauss[0], popt_gauss[1], popt_gauss[2])

plt.plot(x_fit, y_fit, color="red", linewidth=1, label="Gauß-Fitfunktion")
```

Hope this works for you.